# copying items from a nested list to more than one list

Tags: python, list

I have a function that has an empty list which gets filled up as a nested list by user input.

```
def main():
    inputs = []
    inputs_n = int(input("Insert the number of inputs: "))
    print("Input format: n,n,n")
    for num in range(2**inputs_n):
        input_value = input(f"Insert [{num + 1}] row with inputs: ")
        inputs.append(list(int(input_row) for input_row in input_value.split(",")))
```

this results in the list *inputs* **for example** like so: `inputs = [[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]`.
Now I extended the above function by adding 3 empty lists, these lists should be filled up by the respective index number.

```
 row_1 = []
 row_2 = []
 row_3 = []
 for lists in inputs:
     for index in lists:
         row_1.append(inputs[index - 1][0])
         row_2.append(inputs[index - 1][1])
         row_3.append(inputs[index - 1][2])
 print(row_1, row_2, row_3)
```

The expected result from the print (*following the example from above*) should be like so, row_1:`[1,1]` row_2:`[0,1]` row_3:`[1,1]`.
But the result that I get (*still following the example list from above*) is like so:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Hope the question is clear enough now, If you need any further explanation feel free to comment.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you, editing it right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, sorry for the bad question format.
Anyways, here is the solution to my question:
the solution is fairly simple, all what happened is that I added an unneeded extra for loop `for index in lists` which unnessecarily added extra items to my list. the solution is as follows

```
row_1 = []
row_2 = []
row_3 = []
for lists in inputs:
    row_1.append(lists[0])
    row_2.append(lists[1])
    row_3.append(lists[2])
```

and if we continue with the example input above `inputs = [[1,0,1], [1,1,1]]`
We do indeed get our desired output `[1, 1] [0, 1] [1, 1]`

to anyone who landed on this same question, just try and add a debugger under your tool belt, would be really useful. If not viable, don't get discouraged from the error, take a break and you will most likely figure it out.